# Comparing Largish DataSets C# or SQL for OFAC

Tags: c#, sql, sdn

I need to find a way to compare 2 large datasets quickly, we are comparing a list of names (approximately 31,000 entries) against OFAC's SDN List (approximately 30,000 entries, a combination of the main SDN list and the alternate names SDN list).  If I'm doing my math correctly, this combination would result in a datatable with over 900,000,000 entries.  Based on my extrapolations it would take about 10 days for this to finish on my pc, using Parallel.ForEach loops, if it takes 30 seconds to compare 1 name against the OFAC SDN information.  I'm using a C# console app for my testing.  The data is stored in MS SQL database.  I'm open to using either source for the processing, locally or on the SQL Server.

Please forgive me if my estimations are wrong, but the main crux is, this is going to take a long time.

This is for the initial process.  In subsequent comparison runs, I'll check the names against a results table to see if the comparison has already been done and skip it if it's already been done.

How do I speed this up so the initial comparison process does not take so long???  Thanks for your help and tips!!

Here's my console app code.

```
List<CUSTOMER> CUSTOMERList = conn.CUSTOMERs.Take(1).ToList();

List<OFAC_Main> ofacMainList = conn.OFAC_Main.Include("OFAC_Alternate").Include("OFAC_Address").Include("Ofac_RemarkComment").ToList();

int minimumCharacterCount = Convert.ToInt32(Setting.SelectByName("MinimumCharacters").Value);

//loop through the CUSTOMER list
Parallel.ForEach(CUSTOMERList, CUSTOMER =>
{
    //find the values in the possible name fields in each CUSTOMER record
    List<string> CUSTOMERNames = GetNames(CUSTOMER);

    //loop through the names found in the CUSTOMER record
    Parallel.ForEach(CUSTOMERNames, CUSTOMERName =>
    {
        //if the CUSTOMER name is longer than the minimum character count setting, process it
        if (CUSTOMERName.Length > minimumCharacterCount)
        {
            //loop through the SDN list and process the name
            Parallel.ForEach(ofacMainList, ofacName =>
            {
                //convert List to json object
                //string ofacJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ofacName);

                //if the SDN name is longer than the minimum character count setting, process it
                if (ofacName.SDN_Name.Length > minimumCharacterCount)
                {
                    Compare(CUSTOMERName.ToString(), ofacName.SDN_Name.ToString());
                }

                //if the SDN Name has Alternate names too, need to run the comparison against it too
                if (ofacName.OFAC_Alternate.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (OFAC_Alternate alternateName in ofacName.OFAC_Alternate)
                    {
                        //if the SDN Alternate name is longer than the minimum character count setting, process it
                        if (alternateName.Alt_Name.Length > minimumCharacterCount)
                        {
                            Compare(CUSTOMERName.ToString(), alternateName.Alt_Name.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does Compare() do?

Comment: It passes the 2 names to the function that calculates the JaroWinkler distance and SoundEx scores between them.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? That's what will determine if it can be parallelized or indexed effectively. Fuzzy searches using Levenshtein distance calculations are accelerated by using tries or trigrams for example.

Comment: SQL Server itself can't help here. It has Full Text Search indexes but no fuzzy matching operators. It *can* be used with Python though, which has ready-made packages created for this job specifically. SQL Server's Machine Learning services allow calling Python scripts through `sp_execute_external_script`. The real trick will be to pre-load and index the data you want to search before you start querying it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I'm trying to compare 2 lists of names against one another.  I have the JaroWinkler and SoundEx functions in SQL functions and C# options.  These 2 functions are mentioned by name on the OFAC website, and we want to use the same one's they are using.  The problem I'm having is one list of names has around 31,000 entries and the combined SDN Name and Alternate name list add up to around 30,000 names.  What I'm trying to accomplish is how to speed up the initial comparison run so it runs faster than 5 days.  Thanks for your suggestions, they have been helpful.

Comment: You wrote that at the very top of the question. The facts remain the same. 30K rows is very little data but trying to parallelize brute force matching will be very slow no matter what. There are libraries that use indexing structures that can improve matches *without* requiring parallelization.

Comment: And Python has several dozens of battle tested packages that can do what you want like [this one for JaroWinkler](https://github.com/maxbachmann/JaroWinkler) - just the very first result I found.

Answer (score 1):

I agree ! You need to chop this down into small pieces. One idea would be to do the joining and filtering in SQL, then, when you have a table with all the potential comparisons, start looping through doing your Compare(). The join you need is called a cartesian join, and it's what you get if you don't specify any join criteria. That way, you can store the result of Compare() in the Comparisons table, and throw out any comparisons that are not interesting. so something like this...

```sql
CREATE table Comparisons (...)
INSERT into Comparisons(...) (
SELECT C.Name, O.OFAC_Alternate, OFAC_Address, OFAC_RemarkComment
FROM Customers C, OFAC_Main O
WHERE len(C.Name) > @minimumCharacterCount
and( 
   len(O.OFAC_Name) > @minimumCharacterCount
   or len(O.OFAC_Alternate > @minimumCharacterCount)
)
-- you can set some arbitrary filter here to chop this mega table into smaller pieces.
and C.id < 1000
)
```

This part won't take long. It's the Compare() function that will kill you. I have no idea how you're going to speed that up.

Comment: Creating the table would take some time, but it might be the best option.  Thanks!